# Linq to SQL outer join with Timespan

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm using L2S and I have to perform one left outer join with VisitFromTime and VisitToTime values in right table. Code looks like:

```
from d in db.Doctors
join p in db.plans on d.DoctorID equals p.DoctorID
into temp
from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new MyModel
{
   ....
   ....
   VisitTimeFrom = t!=null?t.VisitTimeFrom:new TimeSpan(),
   VisitTimeTo = t!=null?t.VisitTimeTo:new TimeSpan()
}
```

It gives me runtime exception that explicit conversion from bigint to time is not supported in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

is VisitTimeFrom and VisitTimeTo bigint in the database?

If so surely you want

```
VisitTimeFrom = t!=null?t.VisitTimeFrom:0,
VisitTimeTo = t!=null?t.VisitTimeTo:0
```

Comment: they are time(7) in db and Liqn designer makes them using TimeSpan

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `t.VisitTimeFrom` and `t.VisitTimeTo` are both timespans.

Comment: Please post the complete code instead of those "..."-s in the code? can it be related to other fields, or are you sure the problem is with these fields exactly?

Comment: Problem is with these two fields. i have solved the problem will post an answer in a while